# Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS : Brightness slider not showing

Tags: nvidia, 22.04, brightness

Brightness slider is not showing beneath the sound slider in the topbar

I first installed ubuntu 20, brightness or anything relateted to brightness was not working, (I tried installing brightness controller, install nvidia drivers and tried xander command too. The keyboard keys f4 and f5 is not working as well)

I then also upgraded the ubuntu to 22.04.3 LTS hoping it would fix it nothing worked.

I hope to get this resolved as soon as possible because we cannot adjust the brightness while we are working. Hope someone will help

In case this is of significance I'm using HP pavillion 15-eg3036 laptop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked, I was kind of doing everything.
My issue was : I was getting error in xrandr

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
```

The file `/etc/default/grub` have

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

What I did:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

Now my brightness slider is working fine

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yh2Sp.png)